# Sortby Collection BackboneJS With Lodash

Tags: sorting, lodash, backbone.js-collections

I have collection like this:

> child{length:3, models:array[3], _byId:Object}

I wanna sort models array, I use lodash like this:

```
var array_of_objects = new ListCollection();

var data = _.sortByOrder(array_of_objects.models, ['id'], ['asc']);
```

And I get result only:

> [child, child, child]

How to sort models arrays with keep length and the Object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to order the original collection, set [`collection.comparator`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-comparator) to `'id'` and then call [`collection.sort()`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-sort).

To order the models without affecting the collection do: [`_.sortBy(collection.models, 'id')`](https://lodash.com/docs#sortBy)

Note that these will order the `Models`, not native js arrays. If your looking to operate on a raw collection of arrays, get a copy of the collection with `var models = JSON.parse(collection.toJSON())` and then follow the instructions for `_.sortBy`.